# Ionic/Angular app connecting to sqlite on Electron platform using typeorm

Tags: angular, sqlite, ionic-framework, electron, typeorm

I'm developing an Ionic Angular app and am targeting both ios and Electron as my platforms. For development purposes, I use the browser as an additional target.

I use typeorm and sqlite via the @capacitor-community/sqlite plugin to provide a persistency layer in my app. These are the versions of the relevant packages:

```json
"@capacitor-community/electron": "^4.1.2",
"@capacitor-community/sqlite": "^5.0.7-2",
"@capacitor/core": "3.4.1",
"@ionic/angular": "^7.0.4",
"@ionic/core": "^7.0.4",
"sql.js": "^1.6.2",
"typeorm": "^0.2.44",
```

This setup works great on ios. For the browser and Electron platforms it worked as well until recently when I started to test using bigger data sets.

In that case I was running into limitations of the sql.js driver as it virtualises the database in memory (see [the project's README](https://github.com/sql-js/sql.js/blob/master/README.md).

On ios, the plugin switches to a native sqlite driver, using the following configuration:

```js
import { createConnection } from 'typeorm';
...
await createConnection({
  synchronize: true,
  entities: [...],
  type: 'cordova',
  database: 'cache.db',
  location: 'default',
  migrationsTransactionMode: 'none',
});
...
```

The browser/Electron config was the following:

```js
{
  synchronize: true,
  entities: [...],
  type: 'sql.js',
  autoSave: true,
  location: 'browser',
}
```

In case the Electron platform was detected, I added a new config trying to connect to the sqlite driver instead of the `sql.js` one:

```js
{
  synchronize: true,
  entities: [...],
  type: 'sqlite',
  database: 'cache.db',
}
```

However, when launching the Electron app, I get the error `this.driver.connect is not a function`.

I've been trying to figure out how to use the native Electron driver, similarly to how on ios it uses the cordova driver, without any luck. I find a lot of different solutions or problems online, some suggesting I should set up the connection on the Electron side, then manually bridge between the main and renderer process, but this seems like a lot of overhead.

The [@capacitor-community/sqlite repository](https://github.com/capacitor-community/sqlite) unfortunately does not include examples specifically for Electron.

Is there anyone who has experience with a similar setup and who can help me pinpoint where the issue in mine is?

Any help greatly appreciated.